# desktop doesn't load after messing with gtk

Tags: gtk

So I guess I majorly screwed up.

In order to install gimp 2.8 I had to upgrade gtk. I first installed 3.4 but it wouldn't work, so I then installed a specific version of 2.4.

Now, after rebooting, my desktop theme had changed and was really ugly, so I decided I'd revert all changes I had made (and gimp 2.8 wasn't really that more useful than 2.6). I went back to my packages and did sudo make uninstall on all of them.

After another reboot, no more desktop, not even a login prompt, all I see is the console which usually briefly appears before the login prompt, with things like "bluetooth started". I can't seem to be able to interact with it. The only time I can make it change is when I press the power button and it shuts down all services before powering off.

I'm now logged in from the install cd, and I'd be really happy to find a fix instead of having to reinstall everything from scratch..

Anybody knows how to? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Start by entering recovery mode and log in with your user name and passwd. Or log in via the cd as you did.

try reinstalling `ubuntu-desktop` with,

- `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop`

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! Unfortunately that didn't fix my system, still get on the same console..

Comment: hmmmm.... . . .

Comment: @ben can't come up with any other simple solution that is faster than a fresh install. So I suggests to just make a fresh install now. it's faster.

Comment: Could it be due to something like the startup script not containing the instruction to load the desktop? I see no error on the screen

Comment: @ben the ubuntu-desktop take cares of that, it should be fixed, try a `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` it might fix some old package version bugs you might have..

Comment: Since you can't do anything at the login prompt, what happens if you log in with your username and password in another terminal (Try Ctrl+Alt+F1)?

Comment: I'm able to login into the terminal with ctrl+alt+f1. From there I have full access to my machine, without the ui (eg network connects automatically). If I try to load unity, i get: symbol lookup error: /usr/local/lib/libgtklibgtk3.so: undefined symbol g_static_resource_limit

Comment: Fixed! As I was trying to reinstall gtk from the terminal, i came across sudo ldconfig. I just needed to update the packages version.